# prolog improvement of an algorithm

Tags: prolog, clpfd, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

```
% SEND+MORE=MONEY
solve(VarList):-
    VarList=[D,E,M,N,O,R,S,Y],     % Οι μεταβλητές του προβλήματος
    Digits=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],  % Οι τιμές των μεταβλητών (τα ψηφία)
    member(D,Digits),
    member(E,Digits),
    member(M,Digits),
    member(N,Digits),     % Ανάθεση τιμών στις μεταβλητές
    member(O,Digits),
    member(R,Digits),
    member(S,Digits),
    member(Y,Digits),
    M=0, S=0,           % Περιορισμοί
    E=D,
    M=D, M=E,
    N=D, N=E, N=M,
    O=D, O=E, O=M, O=N,
    R=D, R=E, R=M, R=N, R=O,
    S=D, S=E, S=M, S=N, S=O, S=R,
    Y=D, Y=E, Y=M, Y=N, Y=O, Y=R, Y=S,
    S*1000+E*100+N*10+D + M*1000+O*100+R*10+E =:= M*10000+O*1000+N*100+E*10+Y.
```

if i decrease the number of varriables VarList. does it improves its speed?

if i `S*1000+E*100+N*10+D + M*1000+O*100+R*10+E =:= M*10000+O*1000+N*100+E*10+Y`

before the checks does it improve its speed?

Comment: Before you optimize this code, you must first make it correct! If I try this in SWI-Prolog, I only get the solution `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. This is probably not intended. If I then ask for more solutions, it fails in about ten seconds.

Comment: [This section of the CLP(FD) implementation for SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd-search) might be of help.

Answer (score 1):

A [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) approach, I am putting my solution in case someone is looking into this problem.

```ml
:- use_module( library( clpfd)).

puzzle(X):-
    X=([S,E,N,D]+[M,O,R,E]=[M,O,N,E,Y]), 
    
    Vars=[S,E,N,D,M,O,R,Y],Vars ins 0..9,
    
    S*1000 + E*100 + N*10 + D +
    M*1000 + O*100 + R*10 + E #=
    M*1000 + O*1000 + N*100 + E*10 + Y,
    
    S#\=0, M#\=0,
    all_different(Vars),
    labeling([],Vars).

?- puzzle(X).
X = ([1, 8, 0, 5]+[4, 2, 7, 8]=[4, 2, 0, 8, 3])
X = ([1, 8, 0, 5]+[6, 2, 7, 8]=[6, 2, 0, 8, 3])
X = ([1, 8, 0, 5]+[9, 2, 7, 8]=[9, 2, 0, 8, 3])
X = ([1, 8, 0, 6]+[3, 2, 7, 8]=[3, 2, 0, 8, 4])
X = ([1, 8, 0, 6]+[5, 2, 7, 8]=[5, 2, 0, 8, 4])
X = ([1, 8, 0, 6]+[9, 2, 7, 8]=[9, 2, 0, 8, 4])
X = ([2, 7, 0, 4]+[5, 3, 6, 7]=[5, 3, 0, 7, 1])....
```

Comment: @WillNess: Consider ĺanguage `none` instead.

Comment: @false one thing I know for sure, I was told on SE meta by "SE stuff" member, that "prolog" highlighting does not exist and the system chooses something it thinks fits best the given piece of code. so, randomly, more or less.

Comment: @false yes, I've just tried it, and it is indeed all one bland color. at least with `ml` all the Variables are consistently colored, so, stand out somewhat, which makes it a bit easier to follow (in my experience at least). what's strange is that sometimes the highlighting turns out good, even graying out the `%` comments.... but what's the name of the language to use for that effect, deterministically, I haven't been able to find out yet.

Comment: @WillNess: Is it really an improvement if integers and variables are colored the same way?

Comment: @false personally for me, it is better they are at least colored differently than everything else. any variety is better than no variety. but YMMV. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, if you move the line

```ml
S*1000+E*100+N*10+D + M*1000+O*100+R*10+E =:= M*10000+O*1000+N*100+E*10+Y
```

*above* what you call "`Περιορισμοί`" ("restrictions", according to Google Translate), it will only become slower because it will needlessly perform the arithmetic calculations which would have been avoided with the restrictions weeding out the illegal digits assignments first.

You also have erroneous equations `S = 0, M = 0, E = D, ...` when it should have been `S =\= 0, M =\= 0, E =\= D, ...`, since all the digits in these numbers are required to be unique and the first digits in the numbers can't be zeroes.

Overall your code's speed *can* be improved, by reducing the domain of available values with each choice of a digit value, using `select/3`, instead of making all the choices from the same unaffected domain `Digits` with `member/2`. This will much reduce the combinatorial choices space, and all the digits picked will be different by construction obviating the inequality checks. The tag [cryptarithmetic-puzzle](/questions/tagged/cryptarithmetic-puzzle)'s info page and Q&A entries should have more discussion and / or examples of this technique (also, the tag [zebra-puzzle](/questions/tagged/zebra-puzzle)).